# libgcc1 depends gcc-5-base but it is not installable

Tags: debian, libgcc, gcc5, gcc4.6

I am trying to install fbi on Debian 7.8 by using `apt-get install fbi`, but I get an error message containing the following:

```
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.5.1-14) but it is not installable.
```

Actually I get this message whenever I try to do anything related to installations using `apt-get`.

what could be the reason behind this error message?

Thanks in advance,
Anas

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to install and configure some missing libraries, like `gcc-5-base_5.3.1-6` and `libgcc1_4.7.2-5` through the commands:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5-base_5.3.1-6_armhf.deb
dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure gcc-5-base_5.3.1-6_armhf.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/libgcc1_4.7.2-5_armhf.deb
dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure libgcc1_4.7.2-5_armhf.deb
```

then I had to correct the dependencies through:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Then the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a broken package in OS. So using following command you can fix it by updating the packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But sometimes there could be errors in when updating. To avoid it find the repository which gives the error and remove the selected mark from the **software and updates**' ***other software*** menu.